# D3: Underestanding why text is not showing on graph

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

First of all I know there have been similar questions here, but I still seem to need a bit of help understanding why what I have done so far is not working.

I am working on [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph) code, and I want to add some text on each node. The lines of code I have messed around with are the following.

I changed this

```
const node = svg.append('g')
      .attr('fill', nodeFill)
      .attr('stroke', nodeStroke)
      .attr('stroke-opacity', nodeStrokeOpacity)
      .attr('stroke-width', nodeStrokeWidth)
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(nodes)
      .join('circle')
      .attr('r', nodeRadius)
      .call(drag(simulation));
```

to

```
const node = svg.append('g')
      .attr('fill', nodeFill)
      .attr('stroke', nodeStroke)
      .attr('stroke-opacity', nodeStrokeOpacity)
      .attr('stroke-width', nodeStrokeWidth)
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(nodes)
      .join('g')
      .call(drag(simulation));

    node.append('circle')
      .attr('r', nodeRadius);

    node
      .append('text')
      .text('example text')
      .attr('fill', 'none')
      .attr('stroke', 'white')
      .attr('stroke-width', 3);
```

and added the following line of code to this section

```
function ticked(): any {
      link
        .attr('x1', d => d.source.x)
        .attr('y1', d => d.source.y)
        .attr('x2', d => d.target.x)
        .attr('y2', d => d.target.y);

      node
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y);

      // Added this line
      node.attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
    }
```

but it's breaking things up. Now the text is rendered but the circles are not.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the original `node` is a selection of circles, in your modified code `node` is a selection of g elements, you'll need to update the tick function to position g elements rather than circles (g elements don't have cx,cy attributes, but can be positioned with a transform).

Comment: @AndrewReid Could you show me how I should update the tick function?

Comment: Andrew is right. You will need to use transform to move the `<g>` elements  instead of circles' `cx`, `cy` and append `<circle>` and `<text>` inside those `<g>`s. I made changes in this fork: https://observablehq.com/@shreshthmohan/force-directed-graph (Look for comments with `SM: change` to look for changes I made.)